# $JAVA_HOME resets after every terminal login

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, openjdk

I just installed openjdk-8-jdk. I already had openjdk-7-jdk installed. When I ran `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it printed `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`.

So I tried changing the $JAVA_HOME variable but it resets to above path every time I re-open the terminal.
I have tried setting it in `/etc/enviroment` `/etc/profile` `/etc/bash.bashrc` `~/.bashrc` but to no avail.

How can I change it? Also, where the $JAVA_HOME is currently set?

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.profile` that shouldn't be there? Just a stab in the dark...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It was ridiculous mistake by me.

As I set `JAVA_HOME` in so many files, in all the mess I set it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` in `~/.bashrc`. So every time I opened the terminal it changed to this no matter what was in all the other files, as `~/.bashrc` runs every time teminal is opened.

Answer (score 6):

Login to your account and open `.bash_profile` file

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Set `JAVA_HOME` as follows using syntax `export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java-bin-directory>/java`
If you want changes effected without logout, enter command below:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do the changes in /etc/environment then changes will be for current session only. /etc/profile is right place to update paths permanently.You need to make changes in profile under /etc

follow below steps. this should solve your issue

```
sudo vim /etc/profile
```

add below 2 lines :

```
export JAVA_HOME="Your path to jdk folder"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

to apply changes immediately run below commmand:

```
source /etc/profile
```

in the next system reboot changes will be picked automatically.

Comment: Still reverts to 1.8 after these changes

Answer (score 2):

You should not set this yourself, if it can be helped. To change which Java version to use, see this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Choosing_the_default_Java_to_use).

Snippet:

> If your system has more than one version of Java, configure which one
>   your system uses by entering the following command in a terminal
>   window

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

> This will present you with a selection that looks similar to the
>   following (the details may differ for you):

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).  
Selection Path Priority Status 
———————————————————— 
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode 
1 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java 3 manual mode  

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

Comment: Does `sudo update-alternatives --config java` sets the `JAVA_HOME` variable too?

Comment: Sorry, if it was specifically only about $JAVA_HOME your question was about, my answer was not well researched. On my system (14.04.03) $JAVA_HOME is not set at all.

Comment: My system says:
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.